# Two column layout: align text in left box left and right box right. When right box breaks, align text left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox 2 column layout with 2 divs containing text.

Text in the left box is left aligned, text in the right box is right aligned.

However, when I shrink the viewport and the boxes wrap, I want the text in the box that was previously right to also be left-aligned.

Here is an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f71z0m2t/1/)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="leftContainer">
  This is my left aligned Text
  </div>
  
  <div class="rightContainer">
  This is text that should be right aligned when the box doesn't wrap and left aligned when it does.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.leftContainer{
  text-align: left;
}
.rightContainer{
  text-align: right;
}
```

[This case is perfect - both containers are left/right and the texts are aligned accodingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGTIZ.png)

[When the container breaks the text of "rightContainer" should be left aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GItm9.png)

I tried to use media queries for it but sometimes the media query condition is satisfied but the row still doesn't break because the texts are not long.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: can you share a little more CSS?

Comment: Sorry, sure! I added a better example above.

Answer (score 0):

use flex basis on columns along with media query.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-column, .right-column{
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.left-column, .right-column{
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  
  .left-column, .right-column{
    flex: 0 0 48%;
  }

  .right-column{
    text-align:right;
  }
}
```